# User and account object is coming undefined from jwt params in Nextjs 14 Google OAuth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, next-auth

I'm integrating Google Sign-in into my Next.js 14 project using NextAuth. However, I'm encountering an issue where the jwt function is returning only the token and not the expected account and user objects. Any insights into this behavior would be appreciated.

````
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 //1d
    },
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, ...rest }) {
            // console.log('sign in', {user, account, profile, rest});
            if (account.id_token) accessToken = account.id_token;
            return true;
        },
        async jwt({token, user, account}) {
            console.log({token, user, account})
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/is_exists', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({ email: token.email }),
                })
                const isUserExists = await response.json();
                // console.log({ isUserExists })
                if (isUserExists.success) {
                    // console.log('user data ', { ...token, ...isUserExists.user, access_token: account.id_token})
                    return { ...token, ...isUserExists.user, access_token: accessToken };
                } else {
                    const data = { email: token.email, username: token.name, password: 'null-pass' }
                    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/register', {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: JSON.stringify(data)
                    })
                    const userData = await response.json();
                    // console.log({ userData, isUserExists })
                    return { ...token, access_token: accessToken };
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error', error)
                return null;
            }
        },
        async session({ session, token, user}) {
            // anything returned from jwt callback will be passed here as token parameter
            session.user = token;
            console.log({session})
            return session
        },
    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export {handler as GET, handler as POST};```
````